# How to use match function of excel to change cell value

Tags: excel, cell

please can you tell me how can it be done as i know there are probably several ways of doing it

i have table

[image]

---

so if i want to reduce the qty of a specific product and its type by typing the product and type in another table along with the qty to be subtracted how do i go about it
so far i have used the following function:

```
=INDEX(A2:J49,MATCH(1,(A2:A40=L12)*(B2:B49=M12),0),5)
```

but this gives me the value of the qty column based on the product and its type

any help will be highly appreciated

thanks

Comment: Please step away from the formula and explain what you want to achieve .

Comment: Please show how data is organized in the other sheet as well.

Answer (score 0):

With out using a macro you cannot change the value of a cell if that cell doesnt have a formula in it

Answer (score 0):

You can create another table, which will show the updated result for product and type, here we will be using the first table as an starting point, adding or subtracting some qtty from the second table, and the result will be shown in thrid table. Otherwise you will be needing VBA code for this task.